# Why does bit.ly encrypt the name of its javascript files?

Tags: javascript, git, bookmarklet

I analayzed network requests while loading the bookmarklet and this is what I saw:

[image]

One of the files is lodash, which I can see by just looking at it.

I know that git stores some of its files by hashes, but why send them to the client this way?

Comment: "Encrypt" implies that someone is going to *decrypt* it, which I doubt. Likely just an elegant way for caching files and ensuring you never use an outdated version, since *the file name is a hash of its contents*; or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

This will force a cache refresh when the website publish new assets.

This allow you to cache `f85.js` for a very long time. then when you change the assets, you have a new hash which will force the browser to download the newer version.

This is almost the same as adding a get parameter (e.g. `somefile.js?hash=a34d`). But filenames allow you to deploy to multiples nodes without downtime. During deploy, you want each versions of your assets to be available on your CDN. That's because until the deployment is complete, some users will access the old version and some the new one. So you absolutely need your old assets to be available for users still accessing Nodes running an older version of your app. A hash force a single filename, which means you have to bring your app down during deploy - otherwise users accessing an old versions risk having broken assets.

Comment: you can do the same thing using a get request appended to the file name I believe.

Comment: @cadegalt Yes, but filenames are more convenient to use with a CDN. But yeah it's that same as adding a get parameter.

Comment: @cadegalt actually added more details as to why the filename matters. It's only the same for the cache purposes, filename actually matters a lot once you have a distributed system running on multiples nodes.